# Multiple account types authentication with asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I need to update a complex recruitment website using Asp.Net MVC. 
Being new to the Claims-Based Identity authentication system I have my doubts, so maybe you can help me in the right direction.

The whole website revolves around two basic entities: Companies and Candidates. They all have their areas of the website and need to login in order to access their data.
Now I know that this has been debated before but I'm not sure I've come to the right conclusion. Every post that I find suggests using "Identity Claims", but somehow it doesn't feel like the right way to go.

First I want to be clear on some points:

- a candidate will never be a company and vice versa.
- the company and candidate entities are very different and complex,
  each having more than 25 properties of which only 5 or so are the
  same.
- both tables have relationships with lots of other different tables in
  the database.

Combining these two entities makes me feel like I'm going to make a mess out of it, and it doesn't feel right from an architectural point of view.

Note: As of it is now, the website solves this problem using the composition pattern.

```
public abstract class UserType
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

public class Candidate : UserType
{
}

public class Company: UserType
{
}
```

So my question is: Is the Claims-Based model still a good Idea for this specific case? If not what would you suggest?

Comment: Because its too short for an answer: Yes.

Comment: Can you expand a little? Or point me into the right direction please. I can't seem to find any articles for multiple account types using Identity Claims

Comment: Can't you just add a role claim to each user, denoting that they are either a Candidate or a Company?  This will work with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: What is wrong with the composition approach? That is exactly how I tackled pretty much the same problem in very similar recruitment application. Perhaps my composition is different from yours - can you expand a bit on your existing solution and tasks that you would like to do with Claims-based authorisation.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the composition pattern (I've edited the post). I just wanted to know if I had other options with this new Claims-Based-Identity model, because in all posts everybody suggests using Claims or Roles.

Comment: @BrendanGreen the problem is not the Role, the problem is how will the single User entity hold data for both a Company and a Candidate? How will it manage different relationships with other tables both for Candidate and Comapny? For example a Company is mandatory to have a PersonOfContact, whereas a Candidate is mandatory to have a CV.